# AdMob Ads stopped showing after update on Android

Tags: android, android-studio, admob, ads, adsense

Yesterday morning i released a new update to my app.
I only modified some minor changes, nothing important.
Before the release the app was tested in different devices and the ads were okay.
Hours after the release the banners stopped showing.

In today's AdMob insights i can see an increase, since yesterday, in "AdMob network Requests" but a decrease in "impressions".

The implementation is well done because if i change the banner id to the test id, the test banners show up.

I didn't recibe any email of infractions or policy... nothing!

Right now i'm about to release a new update implementing a new banner (different banner id). I'll write here if it works.

But i'm still trying to find a solution! 
Thanks!

EDIT:
I found on the Google forum los of other devs with the sa
[(Link here)](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-admob-help-forum/8oc3pebOrFw;context-place=forum/google-admob-help-forum)

Comment: the build you have on your phone, is it from the play store, or from android studio? I notice that whenever I build from Android studio, those debug builds dont have ads.

Comment: Both and sometimes ads don't show

Answer (score 3):

The issue has been solved by the AdMob team. I did nothing and the ads came back.
There was no official communication at all.
By talking with the devs on the google forum (link in question) there was a clear problem when publishing an app to the PlayStore.
I'll update if there is an official answer to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

this issue occur with many developer , you should implement Admob with latest dependency V 17.1.1 [link](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start)

Answer (score -1):

Had the same problem. Turns out that the test ads worked fine in the debug version, but no real ads would appear. All ads showed up fine when I made a release version of the app and loaded it to my phone from Android Studio.